# SwiftUI Concurrency: Run activity ONLY on background thread

Tags: ios, swiftui, concurrency

When my content view loads and its a user's first time opening the app, I contact an API.

But, I don't want this to block the main content. The data I receive will never update/affect the UI. So it should fully run in the background.

Right now, it runs like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @StateObject var settings = Settings()

    var body: some View {

    }
    .task {
            await loadData()
    }

    func loadData() async {
            // Call an api.
            // get some data using URLSession
            settings.data = data
    }
}
```

I get the following error: [SwiftUI] Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive(on:)) on model updates.

And I think I get it: SwiftUI thinks that I want the task to update the UI.

To fix it, I tried:

```
    .task {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            await loadData()
        }
    }
```

But, I get: Cannot pass function of type '@Sendable () async -> ()' to parameter expecting synchronous function type

How would I use dispatch queue in this case? I'm only targeting iOS 15+.

Comment: You're not including the relevant part of the code, which is where you *set* the published value within `loadData` -- that's where the change will happen -- not inside the `task` modifier.

Comment: Edited. This data should never affect the UI.

Comment: It is helpful if you include *real* code -- what you have isn't valid Swift at all. You can't assign a `task` to the outside of a `var body : some View { }`, for example. The answer here is probably to annotate `Settings` (which you haven't shown the code for) as `@MainActor` so that updates to it are published on the main thread.

Comment: Sorry will add real code soon.

Huh, why would I want those updates to be published to the main thread?

Comment: "why would I want those updates to be published to the main thread" -- because you're trying to address the error "Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed". You claim that the data is never used in the UI, but since you're not showing any actual code related to it, it can't be verified.

Comment: So basically even though I don't intend it, my data is somehow affecting the UI...

Comment: Once again, can't say, since you're not showing the code.

Comment: You are changing `settings.data`, presumably, this is an `@Published` property; Changing this will result in the `settings` change publisher firing, invalidating the view; hence the error.  You should not include this sort of procedural code in your view anyway.  It should be in a model object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While using Swift Concurrency system, you can use the `Task.detached(...)` constructor to spawn an unstructured detached task. This task will run concurrently in the background. You can additionally specify the task priority `.background` (equivalent to DispatchQueue `qos`) if high priority of execution is not necessary.

As the async function you are trying to run updates a property which triggers a view redraw (`settings` is declared as an `ObservedObject` and I assume `data` is a `Published` property), thus you must set this property from the main actor.

For this to work, you could do something like this:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @StateObject var settings = Settings()

    var body: some View {
        // Some view...
    }
    .task {
        await loadData()
    }

    func loadData() async {
        await Task.detached(priority: .background) {
            // Call an api.
            // Get some data using URLSession
            await MainActor.run {
                settings.data = data
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Adding on to Louis response (in answer because I cannot comment yet), the priority isn't what runs in the background - it is the `detached` part.

If you run with priority `.background` it won't be prioritized so might take longer to get executed.

You can run something in the background but with high priority too: `Task.detached(priority: .userInitiated) {...}`

Answer (score 0):

To get a background thread you can either mark the async func as `nonisolated` or move it out of the `View` because that protocol is annotated as `@MainActor` (i.e. main thread), e.g.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var data: [Data] = []

    var body: some View {
        ...
    }
    .task {
        data = await loadData()
    }

    // nonisolated uses a background thread
    nonisolated func loadData() async -> data {
            // Call an api.
            // get some data using URLSession
            return await getData()
    }
}

// outside of View uses a background thread
func loadData() async -> [Data] {
            // Call an api.
            // get some data using URLSession
    return await getData()
}
```

A good place for service async funcs is in an [EnvironmentKey](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentkey), like how [AuthorizationController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/authorizationcontroller) works.